# Alguna forma de comprimir o disminuir condicionantes en restricciones de un código que se pide por teclado en Java?

Tags: java, condiciones, arraylist

Hoy mismo he tenido un pregunta de examen en que me pedían las siguientes restricciones para un código que se pedía por teclado:

- Tiene que tener 9 caracteres, de los cuales:

  - El primero tiene que ser un número
  - El segundo tiene que ser un guión
  - Los siguientes 7 caracteres restantes tienen que ser números

El código se pide tres veces, se almacena y se muestra en cada iteración

En el examen no supe hacerlo, y ahora en casa lo he sacado de la siguiente forma que creo que funciona:

```
public class RestringirEntradaTeclado {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //instanciamos la clase Scanner para pedir el código
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //creamos un string para recoger dicho código
        String codigo;
        //creamos dos contadores, para el bucle del pedido y de los caracteres
        int contador = 0, pedido = 1;
        //creamos un ArrayList para almacenar los códigos
        ArrayList<String> catalogo = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        //mientras haya menos de tres pedidos, repetir
        while (pedido <= 3){
            //pedimos el código
            System.out.println("Introduzca el código: ");
            //recogemos el código en la variable
            codigo = teclado.nextLine();
            //creamos un array de caracteres                      
            char[] miChar = new char[codigo.length()];
            //pasamos el código recogido del teclado al array de caracteres
            miChar = codigo.toCharArray();
            //tomamos el primer caracter del array de caracteres y los convertimos a entero
            int n1 = Character.getNumericValue(miChar[0]);
    
            //efectuamos la primera evaluación de si el código tiene 9 caracteres
            if (codigo.length() == 9){ 
                //segunda evaluación, el primer carácter es un número ?           
                if ((n1 >= 0) && (n1 <= 9)){
                    //tercera evaluación, el segundo carácter es un guión ?
                    if (miChar[1] == '-'){
                        //creamos un bucle para evaluar los 7 caracteres restantes
                        for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++){
                            //en cada iteración del bucle, convertimos el carácter del array de caracteres en número
                            int n2 = Character.getNumericValue(miChar[i]);
                            //En la cuatra evaluación, comprobamos que ese carácter sea realmente un número
                            if ((n2 >= 0) && (n2 <= 9)){
                                //aumentamos el contador en 1
                                contador++;
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Las posiciones 3 - 9 tienen que ser números");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("El segundo carácter tiene que ser un guión");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("El primer carácter tiene que ser un número");
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("El código debe constar de un número + un guión en la segunda posición + 7 números");
            }
            //si el contador es igual a 7 de cada uno de los 7 números evaluados
            if (contador == 7){
                //convertimos a String el array de caracteres
                String cod = String.valueOf(miChar);
                //agregamos el String al ArrayList del catálogo
                catalogo.add(cod);
                //imprimimos el ArrayList
                System.out.println(catalogo);
                //reseteamos el contador de los caracteres
                contador = 0;
            }
            //aumentamos en 1 el contador de los pedidos
            pedido++;
        }   
    } 
}
```

La intención sería disminuir tanta evaluación, no sé si habrá posibilidad de hacer un simple if restringiendo lo que se pide en una simple línea tipo:

```
if (caracteres [0-9], '-', [0-9], [0-9], [0-9], [0-9], [0-9], [0-9], [0-9])
```

Un saludo

**EDITADO**

Impresionante, muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas, finalmente, el código me ha quedado así:

```
public class RestriccionesComprimidas {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String codigo;
        int pedido = 1;
        ArrayList<String> catalogo = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        while (pedido <= 3){
            System.out.println("Introduzca el código: ");
            codigo = teclado.nextLine();                      
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]-[0-9]{7}$");
            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(codigo);                                                                           
            if ((mat.matches()) && (codigo.length() == 9)) {
                catalogo.add(codigo);
                System.out.println(catalogo);
            }else{
                System.out.println("El código debe constar de: \n"
                    + "- Primer carácter un número \n"
                    + "- Segundo carácter un guión \n"
                    + "- Siguientes 7 carácter serán números");
            }
            pedido++;
        }
        teclado.close();   
    } 
}
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Investiga sobre expresiones regulares

Comment: Definitivamente debes considerar expresiones regulares. Si no quieres usar expresiones regulares puedes usar un switch case, y al menos usarías tres opciones.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas, precisamente estaba experimentando con el código después de buscar por interner información sobre las expresiones regulares cuando han llegado las respuestas de la solución. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atendiendo a los comentarios sobre mis respuestas algo complicadas te dejo dos formas de solucionar el problema. La primera sin necesidad de expresiones regulares (que son lo ideal en este caso), la segunda usándolas.

## **Solución 1**

**Nota:** Para mejorar la forma de saber si es un número o no, crearemos un método que retorne booleano si cada carácter de un String es un digíto (número). Para ello usaremos el método `codePointAt()` que nos devuelve el código [UNICODE](https://unicode-table.com/es/) del carácter que a su vez es retrocompatible con [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/). Como vemos los códigos de los dígitos van del 48 al 57, por lo cual usaremos eso como referencia en la solución.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3;) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el código:");
            String code = scanner.nextLine();
            if(code.length() != 9) {
                System.out.println("Código inválido." +
                        "\nEl código debe tener una longitud de 9 caracteres");
                continue;
            }
            if (!isNumeric(code.substring(0,1))) {
                System.out.println("Código inválido." +
                        "\nEl primer carácter debe ser un dígito");
                continue;
            }
            if(code.charAt(1) != '-') {
                System.out.println("Código inválido." +
                        "\nEl segundo carácter debe ser un guión");
                continue;
            }
            if (!isNumeric(code.substring(2, code.length()))){
                System.out.println("Código inválido." +
                        "\nLos últimos 7 caracteres deben ser dígitos");
                continue;
            }

            ++i;
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    private static boolean isNumeric(String text) {
        int unicode_code;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            // nos devuelve el caracter unicode del carácter
            unicode_code = text.codePointAt(i);
            if (unicode_code < 48 || unicode_code >57)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Hay que notar que:**

- Primero se evalúa si es de 9 caracteres la cadena
- Para evaluar el primer dígito se manda a llamar el método `isNumeric` y se le pasa el primer carácter.
- Para evaluar el guión, simplemente obtener el segundo carácter del String
- Para evaluar el resto se le pasan desde el 3 carácter hasta el último.
- El método `isNumeric` es estático para poder ser usado dentro de otro contexto estático (**main**), además es privado, pues sólo se usa dentro de la clase en que es declarado y definido, siguiendo así el principio de menor privilegio.

## **Solución 2**

Esta es mucho mejor que la primera solución y hace uso de la clase [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) dado que vamos a hacer uso de [expresiones regulares](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Aquí te dejo una *[cheat sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)* increíblemente útil.

El patrón que pides es X-XXXXXXX, donde cada X es un número.
Usando la *cheat sheet*, entonces podemos construir la siguiente regex:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]-[0-9]{7}$");
// o
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\d-\d{7}$");
```

Donde:

- `^` Le indica que evaluará el inicio de la cadena
- `[0-9]` (también puede ser `\d` pues son sinónimos) representa cualquier dígito entre 0 y 9.
- `-` (Indica un guión explícito)
- `[0-9]{7}` Indica que el grupo anterior (`[0-9]`) debe estar exactamente 7 veces
- `$` Le indica que ahí debe de terminar la cadena

Como verás se simplifica mucho el programa, pues se puede evaluar un patrón de texto

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]-[0-9]{7}");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3;) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el código:");
            String code = scanner.nextLine();
            if(!pattern.matcher(code).matches()){
                System.out.println("Código inválido." +
                        "\nRecuerde que el formato es X-XXXXXXX");
                continue;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Hay que notar que:**

- Para evaluar la expresión regular se debe de comparar si el patrón concuerda con lo ingresado `pattern.matcher(code).matches()`
- En ambas soluciones el contador i, incrementa dentro del ciclo for. Esto para que si el código no cumple con el patrón, no se cuente la vuelta pues la palabra reservada `continue` nos ayuda a omitir el resto de la iteración,

**Nota final:**

Casi nadie lo menciona cuando se está iniciando a programar, pero es buena práctica cerrar el Scanner `scanner.close();` cuando lo dejemos de usar, puesto que es una entrada de datos (*Input Stream*) que solicita recursos al sistema operativo. Aunque al final de la ejecución del programa la JVM cierra todo, es "malo" o mejor dicho perjudicial, el no cerrar los recursos que solicitas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta @Eduardo Jiménez. Me funciona a la perfección. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Puedes tener algo así: la expresión regular que necesitas para validar el dato es:

```
/^[0-9]-[0-9]{7}$/
```

Para usar expresiones regulares en Java se usa el `package java.util.regex`
Esta tiene dos clases que te facilitarían mucho la solución a tu problema: Pattern y Matcher. Tu código quedaría así:

```
 Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]-[0-9]{7}$");
 Matcher mat = pat.matcher(codigo);                                                                           
 if (mat.matches()) {
     System.out.println("Es válido");
 } else {
     System.out.println("El código debe constar de un número + un guión en la segunda posición + 7 números");                                                                                
 }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta @Jean Gotopo, la línea de expresión regular me funciona a la perfección.